# Как правильней сделать вывод рекурсией?

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, рекурсия

Вопрос логический. Есть рекурсия, которая что-то выводит. В общем-то неважно какая. Главное - она выводит html код. Вопрос в том, что в MVC ей не место в контролере, как и в модели. А положить ее во view тоже нехорошо. Куда логичнее? Может есть идеи?

```
     function Go(p_id) { 
if ($param !=0){
        $model = Table::find()->where(['id'=>$p_id])->one();
        echo("<LI>\n");
        echo("<a HREF=\"" . "?ID=" . $model->id . "\">" . $model->name . "</a>" . "  \n");
        $this->actionGo($model->p_id);

    }
```

Comment: логичнее в контроллере данные подготовить, а в шаблоне их вывести

Comment: Как я понимаю, controller по логике отвечает только за передачу данных от model ко view, т.е. в идеале там не должно быть обработки данных. В Yii это немного не так, ну да ладно. Если я вас правильно понял - то сначала Вы предлагаете рукурсией собрать данные в массив, в контроллере, а затем это массив обойти во view и еще раз обойти? Такое решение мне подходит, но предположим, записей будет 2-3 тысячи.... многовато ресурсов(. И в итоге - во view функция рекурсии - что нехорошо

Comment: по разному бывает. иногда бывают "легковесные" модели и  "тяжелые" контроллеры, иногда наоборот. Если вам некое дерево надо извлечь, то сделайте это с помощью одного sql-запроса, а не дергайте каждую запись отдельно. Когда вы подготовите данные, то во вью шаблоне вам нужно только вывести список, рекурсия никакая не потребуется, при правильно/удобно подготовленных данных. Мб конечно вам и не иерархию строк надо выбрать, но похоже на то. Мб стоит описать задачу более подробно, что вы вообще делаете?

Comment: Как вариант можно изучить код вывода деревьев, там тоже используется рекурсия.
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager

Comment: @teran, у меня-то задача простая: есть табличка | id | p_id | name |, получаю id записи - и мне надо вывести родителей записи, запись, и потомков записи. Именно в такой последовательности. Причем, конкретно в моем случае, таких родителей/потомков не будет более 20-30 штук. Но мне интересно, если, бы таких записей было n и мне надо было бы вывести всю иерархию.

Comment: @AlexMaxTM я так понимаю, он просто запрашивает данные из БД и выводит виджетом. Кстати, да, виджет - неплохой варинат.

Comment: Я думаю тут не стоит думать о высоком MVC когда вы в рекурсии запросы к базе делаете и деревья выводите. Одно "кольцо" и будет ваш скрипт рандомно по памяти падать и привет радостный поиск.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут не стоит думать о "высоком MVC" когда вы в рекурсии запросы к базе делаете и деревья выводите. Одно "кольцо" и будет ваш скрипт рандомно по памяти падать и привет радостный дебагинг.

Виджеты кидающие запросы в базу плохо. Все запросы должны быть в модели. Table::find()->where(['id'=>$p_id]) в контроллере или отображении нарушение концепции MVC.

В модели должен быть метод getTree который одним запросов выгребает все дерево, либо его раздел. Контроллер эти данные передает отображение, а там уже виджет вы с ними вызовите или цикл напишите нужно смотреть по ситуации. В одном месте цикл во отображении, в нескольких местах виджет или отдельное отображение.